# Como instalar Visual Studio 2017 Offline?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows

Llevo tiempo intentando instalar el Visual Studio 2017 Offline sin resultados.

Tengo copiado el Visual Studio 2017 en mi PC, alrededor de 44 Gb.
He instalado los 3 certificados que vienen la carpeta **certificates**:

```
manifestCounterSignRootCertificate.cer
manifestRootCertificate.cer
vs_installer_opc.RootCertificate.cer
```

Luego ejecuto el comando desde la carpeta **Setup** `vs_Enterprise.exe --layout "C:\VS2017" --lang en-US`
Y aun asi sigue intentando descargarlo de internet.

Si ejecuto el instalador directo `vs_Enterprise.exe` me deja escoger los Workloads que quiero instalar, pero sea cual sea mi eleccion va directo a Internet a descargarlos.

Alguien sabe si estoy haciendo algo mal, o he omitido algun paso ?

Comment: Has leido esto? https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Pikoh ya he ejecutado el comando vs_Enterprise.exe --layout c:\vs2017 --lang en-US, eso inicia una descarga de unos 65MB, al completarla en la propia consola comienza a verificar la existencia de todos los paquetes que tengo copiado, pero al finalizar, comienza a descargarlos de internet.

Comment: Pero has creado la cache local como te indica en el documento que te he enlazado?

Comment: Segun esa misma documentacion se hace asi no? >> Para crear un diseño local completo con todas las características (lo que llevará mucho tiempo—, ya que tenemos multitud de características), ejecute:
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --lang en-US

Comment: _Paso 1: Descargar el programa previo de Visual Studio_,_Paso 2: Crear una caché de instalación local_,Para el desarrollo web y de escritorio .NET, ejecute:
`vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio --includeOptional --lang en-US`

Comment: _Paso 3: Instalar Visual Studio desde la caché local_. Lo que  haces en los primeros pasos es "crear el instalador offline". Pero para ello,obviamente debe descargar los paquetes

Comment: Echa un vistazo tambien al blog del amigo @fredyfx : http://fredyfx.com/post/instalar-visual-studio-2017-iso-offline/

Comment: Pues muchas Gracias por la referencia al blog. Mas claro imposible. Al final siempre tiene que descargar las cosas de Internet. Lastima que desde donde estoy sea imposible realizar esa descarga. Pensaba que teniendo esos 44GB copiados en la PC podia comenzar a trabajar sin tener que usar Internet. Saludos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88409/discussion-between-warner-and-pikoh).